# Aerospike TTL updates

Tags: aerospike, ttl

I am trying to update .put() into existing records in Aerospike using the python client.

I was excited to discover that you can actually put into existing records and not update the TTL as shown here (meta params): https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html?highlight=ttl#aerospike.Client.put . I used to do this by reading the TTL and then re-setting it on the new put.

However, I discovered that when you use the aerospike.TTL_DONT_UPDATE option, the TTL resets to the cold-start-evict-ttl that is set on the namespace. How do I avoid that and just maintain the previous TTL unchanged?

Crossposted to Aerospike forums: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/aerospike-ttls-on-put/4993

Comment: If you are going to crosspost, it is good etiquette to link to the other post[s]. This helps avoid the 'Wisdom of the Ancients' problem in the future.

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/cross-posting-to-from-other-sites-such-as-stack-overflow/4526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not posting sample code is to a 'bug report' the equivalent of not washing your hands after using the toilet. It also would help if you simply provided the version of your server and the version of your Python client.

**ttl-test.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
import sys
from aerospike import exception as e
from time import sleep

config = { 'hosts': [ ('127.0.0.1', 3000) ] }

try:
    client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
except ex.ClientError as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
    sys.exit(1)

key = ('test', 'demo', 'foo')

try:
    # Write a record
    client.put(key, {
        'name': 'Hey Joe',
        'age': 66
        }, meta={'ttl': 4})
except ex.RecordError as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
client.put(key, {'z': 26}, meta={'ttl': aerospike.TTL_DONT_UPDATE})

try:
    (key, meta) = client.exists(key)
    print(meta)
except ex.RecordError as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))

sleep(5)

try:
    (key, meta) = client.exists(key)
    print(meta)
except ex.RecordError as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))

client.close()
```

And now to test it:

```
$ python ttl-test.py 
{'gen': 2, 'ttl': 4}
None
```

Seems to work. Note that I'm using a server version >= [3.10.1](https://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.10.1)

Comment: Apologies, the exact same code doesn't work the same on aerospike 2.2.3 although it should, based on the docs.

Comment: Are you talking about [release 2.2.3](https://www.aerospike.com/download/client/python/notes.html#2.2.3) of the Python client for Aerospike?  Actually this constant was added with [release 2.0.6](https://www.aerospike.com/download/client/python/notes.html#2.0.6) but you need to have your client talk to a server whose version is >= 3.10.1

Comment: I see, that explains it and apologies for the confusion around this. I neglected the server's version, so I guess that's where my problem is.